# How to win it in less moves

Tags: strategy, learning

From this point I tried to win this match but it took a very long chase. I know there is some shorter way to win it as my mobile chess-free app asked to resign after moving my white knight, but couldn't figured out how to win it in lesser moves.

```
[fen "1nb2rk1/q3pp2/2p1n1pQ/1p1pP2p/rP1P4/2PB1N1P/P4PP1/R1B2RK1 w Q - 0 1"]
```

Comment: The sad truth is that Black can postpone his demise by giving up material, but he is lost nonetheless... In my opinion Bxg6 is the easy enough to convert.

Comment: is it black or white to move here?

Comment: @DarrenH https://i.imgur.com/MANXaCO.gif

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.Nh4 is best, preparing to decisively take on g6. Black can't do much to brace for this move. For example, 1...Rd8 2.Nxg6 fxg6? 3.Qxg6+ Ng7 (3...Kf8 4.Bh6+ leads to mate) 4.Bh6 e6 5.Qh7+ Kf8 6.Qh8+ Ke7 7.Qxg7+ Ke8 8.Bg6+ Qf7 9.Qxf7#.

It would be better if Black played ...f5 either on the first or second move, but this clearly isn't challenging since then your knight just takes on g6 for free, and White's attack is crashing through.